# Scikit-maad and Soundecology results acoustic indices

Tags: python, r

I have a problem in the analysis of the acoustic indices. I tried calculating different indices both with Scikit-maad and Soundecology, but the results at the end are hardly comparable, here's an example of the results for ADI.

[Results Comparisons](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EbtYo.png)

We checked that all the parameters set for the analysis were the same and we came to the conclusion that the problem is in how Soundecology and Maad calculate the spectrogram.
Maad uses some parameters that we do not fully understand and we cannot find in R packages that should do the same thing (like ReadWave of TuneR or Spectro of seewave).

https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tuneR/tuneR.pdf
https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/seewave/versions/1.0/topics/spectro

Python-code example

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    fullfilename="wav_files/AM08_Grotte-New_2019-10-04_0FE081F80FE081F0_2019-07-26_000000_UTC.wav"
    wave, fs = sound.load(filename=fullfilename, channel='left', detrend=False, verbose=True)
    Sxx_power,tn,fn,ext = sound.spectrogram (wave, fs, window='hanning',
                                             nperseg = 1024, noverlap= None,
                                             verbose = False, display = False,
                                             savefig = None)
    adi = features.acoustic_diversity_index(Sxx_power, fn, fmin=0, fmax=10000, bin_step=1000, dB_threshold=-50, index='shannon')
    print(adi)
```

R code example

```
a <- readWave("wav_files/AM08_Grotte-New_2019-10-04_0FE081F80FE081F0_2019-07-26_000000_UTC.wav")
adi <- acoustic_diversity(a, max_freq = 10000, db_threshold = -50,
freq_step = 1000, shannon = TRUE)
```

For example, we do not find a matching parameter for 'nperseg' in any R package that calculates the spectrogram.

I would be very grateful if you could help us with this.

Thank you very much,
Valeria

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you very much to point out the issue.
I found the reason that explains the discrepancy between the result from soundecology library in R and scikit-maad package in Python.

- **In soundecology**, the DC value is never subtracted from the original signal (i.e. no detrend of the signal) meaning that the mean value of the signal is not null. Depending on the electronic of the audio recorder, the signal is a bit above or below the zero level.
- **In scikit-maad**, the DC value is removed by default when loading the signal (but you can switch off the option : `detrend=False`) and also when computed the spectrogram ( I've just added a switch off option, `detrend=False`).

The problem is now in the function `all_spectral_alpha_indices` which computes all indices at the same time, where the input argument is a detrend spectrogram (i.e the dc value is already subtracted from the signal).

There are two options :

1. I've just added optional arguments `ADI_dB_threshold` and `AEI_dB_threshold` in the function `all_spectral_alpha_indices` in order to change the threshold used for the calculation. A "good" value seems to be -30. With -30, the ADI and AEI from maad is well correlated with soundecology but the values are a bit different, especially for low values (when there is not much activities). See the colab notebook below.
2. Compute ADI and AEI as soundecology. An example is provided for both functions.
   Here is the example for ADI :

```py
s, fs = maad.sound.load('../data/cold_forest_daylight.wav', detrend=False)
Sxx, tn, fn, ext = maad.sound.spectrogram (s, fs, nperseg=int(fs/10), noverlap=0, mode='amplitude', detrend=False)
ADI = maad.features.acoustic_diversity_index(Sxx,fn,fmax=10000)
print('ADI : %2.2f ' %ADI)
```

The main problem with this solution is that you need to load the signal and compute the spectrogram without detrend specifically for ADI (and AEI) which could increase the time to process a large dataset.

Here, I wrote an script to explain the issue and give you both solutions to fix the issue and compare the results.
https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1xoErUfqN1_AX0ibujOlnt8bKO23DUXFR#scrollTo=Poydb8kSF9VD

I hope this helps.

Sylvain